# Method using openById() does not work if called from onEdit()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I want to use the data of a database spreadsheet in another interface spreadsheet. I have a `copySelectedRow()` function, which does not work if I call it from `onEdit()`, but works if I call it from somewhere else (For example `incrementByOne()`).

```
//runs if the id cell is modified
function onEdit(e)
{ 
  var range = e.range;
  var columnOfCellEdited = range.getColumn();
  var rowOfCellEdited = range.getRow();

  if ( columnOfCellEdited === 2 && rowOfCellEdited === 1 )
  {
    Logger.log( "triggered" );
    copySelectedRow();
    chooseGroupForCollisionCheck();
  }
};

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

//increment the value of the id by one
function incrementByOne()
{ 
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var targetSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var tempNumber = targetSheet.getRange( 1, 2 ).getValue();
  targetSheet.getRange( 1, 2 ).setValue( tempNumber + 1 );

  copySelectedRow();
  chooseGroupForCollisionCheck();
}

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------

//copy the chosen row to the appropriate cells of the editor sheet
//if zero sets the cells to default
function copySelectedRow()
{ 
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  Logger.log( "copystart " + ss.getName() );
  var shEdit = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var spreadSheetData = SpreadsheetApp.openById( "1koyd1dIl_SLS5XAc26UO-SBOL9d9Thfd83xzIc900fo" );
  Logger.log( "database " + spreadSheetData.getName() );
  var shData = spreadSheetData.getSheets()[ 0 ];

      var idNumber = shEdit.getRange( 1, 2 ).getValue();
      (...)
}
```

The pictures show the log outputs. Also if I call `incrementByOne()` the logs are fine and the function copies the given row, but if `onEdit(e)` is called, the program stops before getting to the "database" log.
I have no idea why, please help :)

Log after calling `incrementByOne()`

[image]

Log after calling `onEdit(e)`

[image]

Comment: You'll need a installed onEdit trigger rather than a simple one.

Comment: thanks very much :)

Comment: This is explained in documentation btw